# Program won't always print out the longest string

Tags: java, jgrasp

What i'm trying to do below in the code, is get the user to enter two sepearate strings i know i have used first name and last name but just ignore that. So the user enters two strings and it should print the longest string.
my program does not always do this. what do i need to change to make it work?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Q2
  {

    public static void main(String args [])
    {
    Scanner keyboardIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String Fname;
    String Lname;

    System.out.print("Please enter first name: ");
    Fname=keyboardIn.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Please enter last name: ");
    Lname=keyboardIn.nextLine();

  if(Fname.compareTo(Lname) < 0)
  {
     System.out.println(Lname + " Is longest ");
  }
  else if(Fname.compareTo(Lname) > 0)
  {
     System.out.println(Fname + " Is longest ");
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: The `compare` method doesn't (only) compare length. Strings have a `length` method which will do what you want.

Comment: You'll also have to decide what is the spected result when the length of the strings are equal.

Comment: Unrelated : read about Java naming conventions. Variable names go camelCase.

Comment: You can accept this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45381201/program-wont-always-print-out-the-longest-string/45381283#45381283 Hope it resolved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the length

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Q2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner keyboardIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String Fname;
        String Lname;

        System.out.print("Please enter first name: ");
        Fname = keyboardIn.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Please enter last name: ");
        Lname = keyboardIn.nextLine();

        if (Lname.length() > Fname.length()) {
            System.out.println(Lname + " Is longest ");
        } else if (Fname.length() > Lname.length()) {
            System.out.println(Fname + " Is longest ");
        } else {
            // Both are of same length
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is wrong

```
if(Fname.compareTo(Lname) < 0)
  {
     System.out.println(Lname + " Is longest ");
  }
```

strings have a **length** and that is what you need to use in order to compare *first* and *lastname* by checking the numbers of chars that are defining it

why is this wrong

```
Fname.compareTo(Lname)
```

because the result is not considering the number of chars on the string

Comment: This doesn't answer the OPs question. This should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the Strings, not their lengths. 
Your code should be changed to:

```
  if(Fname.length() < LName.length())
  {
     System.out.println(Lname + " Is longest ");
  }
  else if(Fname.length() > LName.length())
  {
     System.out.println(Fname + " Is longest ");
  }
```

I would suggest to also add a case for equality, check if `Fname.length() == LName.length()`

Comment: Thanks everyone for your great answers. I realise now I didn't need to use compareTo all i needed to use was the .length(). Thanks for all your input.

Comment: @MarkDoherty Glad it helped. Please accept an answer to indicate your issue is solved

Answer (score 0):

Java compareTo() method compares string lexicographically. I think a good way would be to use the length() method. See the code below

```
if(Fname.length()<Lname.length())
{
   System.out.println(Lname + " Is longest ");
}
else 
{
   System.out.println(Fname + " Is longest ");
 }
```

I am not sure what you want to do when strings are equal length. So, please make sure you check that case.

Comment: What about equality

Comment: I am typing about it when you posted the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using compareTo method, I suggest using the length method. This allows you to compare string lengths directly and more easily.

Use the following statement as an example:

```
if (Fname.length() > Lname.length()){
  System.out.println(Fname + " Is longest ");
}
```